# ActionBar in os 4.03

Tags: android

I am using an **ActionBar** in my application.

I have three things on my **ActionBar**

1. Logo
2. Tab's
3. Menu's

I am facing a problem in `Tab's` because `Tab's` text going in next line

for example:- I am using **Audio** so it should be in single line(i.e **Audio**)

But in OS 4.03 it looks like :-

```
Aud

io
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Here code to add tab's

```
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(getInfoTabName())
                .setTabListener(new ActionBarTabListener<InfoFragment>(this, 
                        getInfoTabName(),InfoFragment.class, InfoFragment)));
```

Comment: Just firing a guess here : Have you put actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

Comment: And your adding tabs in the following way ?         bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_start)).setTabListener(new TabListener<StartFragment>(this, "start", StartFragment.class)));

Comment: i added my code in my question.